# DNN Development Environment installation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke-7

I am trying to install the DNN develpment environment. Tried about 6 different times. Wtched videoa, followed instructions from different sites. All failed. Keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dnn is not defined
InstallWizard.aspx:1124 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
InstallWizard.aspx:1303 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getInstallProgress' of undefined
InstallWizard.aspx:1106 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out problem. It was my IIS.. Web browsing was disabled in the IIS features.